# Referencing Images within Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, maps

I have a javascript map I'm using and I'm trying to add an image to the tooltip

Here is the code:

```
var shardicon = L.Icon.extend({
        iconUrl: 'images/A.png',
        shadowUrl: '',
        iconSize: new L.Point(20, 30),
        iconAnchor: new L.Point(10, 15),
        popupAnchor: new L.Point(-0, -20)
    });

    var shard = new shardicon()
    var marker7 = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(51.504409, -0.086335), {icon: shard})
    marker7.bindPopup("<h1>The Shard</h1>");
```

when I try to add an image reference into the HTML bit (the shard bit) it closes the 'quote marks' and breaks.

Any idea on how I would go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you're missing semicolons on your `var` lines.

Comment: Could you give me an example please? :)

Comment: He means that you should terminate every statement with a semicolon, like this: 

var shard = new shardicon();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, you can use both double quote and single quotes, using one to delimit the outside string for the JS interpreter and the other for your HTML like this:

```
marker7.bindPopup("<h1>The Shard<img src='images/A.png'></h1>");
```

or, it can be done like this too:

```
marker7.bindPopup('<h1>The Shard<img src="images/A.png"></h1>');
```

Comment: brilliant! I actually figured this out by accident but it was exactly the same solution as yours! Thanks!